# Selenium WebDriver randomly stops code entirely and never runs the next line of code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a huge issue because I can't close the driver using driver.quit() due to it getting stuck and it doesn't error so I can't handle the errors. I've been working at this for 2 days now. It usually yields at the end of the program when I try to call driver.quit(), however, this isn't the first version of the program. Previous versions of this used 2 drivers instead of 1 and it would yield at a seemingly random point in time.

I'm not entirely sure what the cause is, but I suspect it's time.sleep(). I tested some things and found out that the only consistency on where this would occur in the program is after using time.sleep(). I haven't tested the program entirely without using time.sleep() because I need it for this program, but after lessening the amount of time.sleep()'s in my program, It seemed to get stuck much less than it used to. **So I can't say for sure it's time.sleep(), that's just what I somewhat suspect.**

Now, **a lot of the time the program works PERFECTLY**, but the problem is I need this code to iterate thousands of times, and after about 50 or so iterations, it completely gets stuck and I have to end the program manually.

Code to repro (you're gonna have to change some file paths and usernames.txt is just a long list of names):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os
import random
import string
import time
import os
import secrets
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from pystyle import Colorate, Colors, Center
from threading import Thread

driver = None

number_of_accounts = 10000

max_threads = 1
current_threads = 0

error = f"    {Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}[{Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}!{Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}]{Fore.RESET}"
success = f"    {Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}[{Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX}+{Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}]{Fore.RESET}"
info = f"    {Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}[{Fore.GREEN}${Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX}]{Fore.RESET}"

banner = Center.XCenter(Colorate.Vertical(Colors.red_to_blue, """


 $$$$$$\  $$$$$$$\  $$\   $$\ $$\   $$\  $$$$$$\  $$\   $$\ $$\     $$\ $$$$$$$\   $$$$$$\  $$\       $$\       
$$  __$$\ $$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ |$$$\  $$ |$$  __$$\ $$ |  $$ |\$$\   $$  |$$  __$$\ $$  __$$\ $$ |      $$ |      
$$ /  \__|$$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$$$\ $$ |$$ /  \__|$$ |  $$ | \$$\ $$  / $$ |  $$ |$$ /  $$ |$$ |      $$ |      
$$ |      $$$$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |$$ $$\$$ |$$ |      $$$$$$$$ |  \$$$$  /  $$$$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |$$ |      $$ |      
$$ |      $$  __$$< $$ |  $$ |$$ \$$$$ |$$ |      $$  __$$ |   \$$  /   $$  __$$< $$ |  $$ |$$ |      $$ |      
$$ |  $$\ $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |\$$$ |$$ |  $$\ $$ |  $$ |    $$ |    $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$ |      $$ |      
\$$$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |\$$$$$$  |$$ | \$$ |\$$$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |    $$ |    $$ |  $$ | $$$$$$  |$$$$$$$$\ $$$$$$$$\ 
 \______/ \__|  \__| \______/ \__|  \__| \______/ \__|  \__|    \__|    \__|  \__| \______/ \________|\________|
"""))

def driveroptions():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("log-level=3")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    # options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    # options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\keekz\Desktop\workspaces\kids_generator\extra\ext.crx") # Updated Captcha Solver (https://nopecha.com/f/ext.crx)
    service = Service(r"C:\Users\keekz\Desktop\workspaces\kids_generator\extra\chromedriver.exe")

    return {"service": service, "options": options}

def randomPassword():
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(25)

def clear():
    print()
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def randomNumber(length):
    numbers = string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(numbers) for i in range(length))

def randomString(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

def getUsername():
    # get a random username from usernames.txt using random module
    with open(r"C:\Users\keekz\Desktop\workspaces\kids_generator\extra\usernames.txt", "r") as f:
        usernamess = f.read().splitlines()
        usernameesz = random.choice(usernamess)
        username21 = usernameesz + randomNumber(6)
        return username21

def create_account():
    global current_threads
    global driver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driveroptions()["service"], options=driveroptions()["options"])

    driveractions = ActionChains(driver)

    try:
        username = getUsername()[:100]
        password = randomPassword()

        print(Center.XCenter(f"{info} {Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX}Generating An Account With The Username: {Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}" + username))

        driver.get("https://getnada.com/")
        
        while len(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"__layout\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p/span[1]/a/button").text) == 1:
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"__layout\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p/span[1]/a/button").text[:(len(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"__layout\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p/span[1]/a/button").text) - 1)]

        driver.get("https://www.crunchyroll.com/")

        driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[4]/div/div[1]").click()
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]/div/h5"))
        ).click()

        driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="email_input").send_keys(email)
        driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="password_input").send_keys(password)

        driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="cx-checkbox__svg").click()
        driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="submit_button").click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/label/input"))
        ).send_keys(username)

        driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]").click()

        time.sleep(2)

        driver.get("https://getnada.com/")

        confirmchecks = 0

        while len(driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(text(), 'Please Confirm Your Account')]")) <= 0 and confirmchecks < 20:
            driver.refresh()
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            confirmchecks += 1

        if confirmchecks >= 20:
            raise Exception("Error: Email never arrived.")
        
        newemail = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(text(), 'Please Confirm Your Account')]")
        driveractions.move_to_element(newemail).perform()
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 150)')

        newemail.click()

        time.sleep(3)

        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "the_message_iframe"))
                )
            )

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS')]"))
            ).click()
        except:
            driver.switch_to.frame(
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "the_message_iframe"))
                )
            )

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'CONFIRM EMAIL ADDRESS')]"))
            ).click()

        time.sleep(1)

        driver.quit()
        
        file = open(r"C:\Users\keekz\Desktop\workspaces\crunchyroll_bot\accounts.txt", "a")
        file.write(f"{email}:{password}\n")
        file.close()

        print(Center.XCenter(f"{success} {Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX}Account Generated Successfully --> {Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}Username: {Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}{username} {Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}Password: {Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}{password} {Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}Email: {Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}{email}"))
        current_threads -= 1
    except Exception as E:
        if E == "Error: Email never arrived.":
            print(Center.XCenter(f"{error} {Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}Error: {Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX}Email never arrived.{Fore.RESET}"))

        driver.quit()

        current_threads -= 1

clear()

print(banner)
print(Center.XCenter(f"""{Fore.LIGHTRED_EX}
{Fore.BLACK}made by intern\n{Fore.BLACK}
"""))

for i in range(number_of_accounts):
    while current_threads >= max_threads:
        time.sleep(1)
    
    thread = Thread(target=create_account)
    thread.start()

    current_threads += 1
```

Solutions I've already tried:

1. Updating Chrome and ChromeDriver
2. Downgrading ChromeDriver to one version lower
3. Running the function in a thread and running a timer that force kills all chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe tasks using subprocess (this didn't work because after the problem occurs once, it occurs a lot more consistently afterward)
4. Reinstalling Python
5. Reinstalling Selenium
6. Uninstalling seleniumwire
7. Factory resetting my PC (and reinstalling everything)
8. Using a different computer
9. Using set_page_load_timeout (code completely stops running, page is already loaded, driver is refusing to quit)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Wrong webdriver path to outdated webdriver.